Using "which" in a sentence but not structuring a correct clause in American English: has this always been a thing?
I couldn't come up with a clearer title.A freestyle example off the top of my head: "She took up drawing recently--which, like, don't you think she isn't actually cut out for that?" Or: "He doesn't care, which, I don't know about you, but I support that wholeheartedly."Something like that. I hope it's clear enough, but if not, I can try to find an example on YouTube.So, as we know, "which" usually refers to a preceding noun or just overall idea, acting as a placeholder in a way, meaning you usually can replace "which" with a noun and get a coherent sentence (He deleted the picture, which upset me. => The action upset me. - source); whereas you can't do that in the case I described. Instead, the "which" is acting as a link between to sentences, in a way, isn't it?I've heard this usage of the word "which" numerous times in spoken American English, the first time I thought about it in such detail was with a streamer who happens to be a New Yorker and habitually uses it a lot like that.My question is: has this always been a thing, or is it a recent trend? I got really curious about the linguistic mechanisms behind it, but I couldn't find any written research that would talk about this.

It's a kind of 'dialect variation', and you can find examples going back to the 19th century.

This question is similar to: Misuse of «which» by natives?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, which is developing in AmE (for some speakers) the sense of  "and as far as I am concerned".  It's a thankless task, which, you can count me out.  ( I say AmE as that's the only dialect I'm regularly exposed to these days.)

It is just a connected speech redirect. She starts to say something after which, then switches to like and then the negative interrogative question. It is not a misuse. All speakers of all languages do this kind of thing when speaking. Listen to people being interviewed on TV. There are all sorts of things that happen with connected speech. I highly doubt it is a New Yorker "thing".

"She took up drawing recently which she isn't actually cut out for?" would be the "correct way" of saying it. "It's a thankless task, which, you can count me out of". However, TimR is right. People misplace the which, but this connected speech issue happens in British English also. It is simply not an AmE thing per se.

I’m voting to close this question because this is just connected speech where people change what they mean on the fly.

Per my answer to much the same question on ELU some years ago, which in the cited context is a "discourse marker". The same applies to immediately following like, and imho to some extent to don't you think and I don't know about you, but.... Such lexical items carry little or no actual meaning.
The example in the ELU question reflects dialectal usage a couple of centuries ago, but it still occurs today. Don't spend too long thinking about the "meaning" or "syntax", because there isn't much.
In the same way that using so as the first word of an ELL question doesn't refer back to an antecedent, which in the cited context doesn't really refer to anything specific in preceding text.

Examples! Examples in that thread on ELU that you linked! From old literature no less! :) Thank you!

I think the situation has been complicated by old-school prescriptive grammar pedagogy.  Multiple generations of native speakers were taught in school not to strand prepositions (though stranding is natural) but they haven't quite mastered how to place the preposition ahead of which and so they drop the preposition altogether. To use my example above: FORMAL:  "It's a thankless task, for which you can count me out."  STRANDED:  "It's a thankless task you can count me out for"   NEITHER-FISH-NOR-FOWL:  "It's a thankless task, which, you can count me out."
